# Possible wrong answer to Spivak calculus chapter on graphs of functions

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

In problem #17-v of Spivak's *Calculus* (3rd edition, chapter 4) the reader is asked to draw the graph of the function $f(x)= [1/x]$, where $[\ldotp]$ is the greatest integer function. I did the problem and then checked the answer, but the answer provided in the manual seems to be wrong. I have attached a link to the image of the answer provided in the manual: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3prm.jpg.

Is the answer wrong?

Comment: Seems right to me. Why do you think it is wrong? The graph of f(x) = 1/x is a hyperbola.

Comment: Yes, it is wrong if [] is the floor function. But I have seen texts where [] was explicitly defined to be the floor function on the positive reals and extended by appropriate symmetry to negative reals (fx. [-1/2]=0, [-3/2]=-1) so you would have to check what definition is used in your text.

Comment: Ah, good point, every negative `step' should be moved one integer down. That's true, and I just checked and Spivak uses the usual definition of the floor function (for arbitrary real $x$).

Comment: @Michal Adamaszek Spivak in his text defines the greatest integer function as "the greatest integer less than or equal to x" so with that definition the given graph is wrong right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does appear to be wrong if it is the plain ‘greatest integer’ function and not something more special. The problem is where $x<0$.

Although $\frac{1}{x} \to 0 $ as $x \to -\infty$, since $\frac{1}{x} < 0$ for all $x < 0$, the lines drawn on the left hand side of a plot of $y = f(x)$ should always be at $y = -1$ or below.

The floor function $\lfloor x \rfloor$ gives the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ and so clearly it will be $0$ only if $x \geq 0$.

Comment: He defines it as usual to be the greatest integer less than or equal to x